# Getting javascript error when using webgrid checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

Used a code answered in below link
[how to retain checkbox value in mvc3 webgrid on pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647097/how-to-retain-checkbox-value-in-mvc3-webgrid-on-pagination/19806148#19806148)

but i get an exeption as shown below and if  i check a checkbox it never call select method of controller please suggest me how to perform as i am new to mvc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in the ternary opeator

```
data: {isChecked: $(this).is(':checked') ? id : $(this).val()}
```

or

```
data: {isChecked: this.checked ? id : this.value}
                               ^ you have `,` here
```

Comment: No same error after changing to data: {isChecked: this.checked ? id : this.value} it says line no 2 object expected ?